# .NET Abstract base class for plugin capability?

Tags: c#, .net, oop, plugins, abstract-class

I'm a newbie, so please forgive me if this is a simple question. I want to create a service that allows third-parties to create plugin dll's for.  The dll's will have a single purpose - to return data of a type via a GetData() method that is potentially different per plugin.

One plugin might want to return a String, another might want to return an Int32, another an Array of Int64's.... etc.

I was thinking of creating an abstract base class that each plugin would derive from.  There would be several methods on the base class - Startup(), Shutdown() and GetData().  GetData() would be called at periodic intervals on each plugin by my service.

What's the best way to define the abstract base class and more specifically GetData() so that each derived plugin class can return different datatypes?  Should I use generics?

Thank you.

Comment: you can define an `interface` which has `GetData()` method which will return type `object` or `dynamic`. Then let your plugin implement that `interface`

Comment: What are you going to do with the data? Do you need to know what type it is?

Comment: There would be a predefined number of allowable types (Int32, Int64, Int32[], Int64[], String, String[] etc.).  Maybe 20 or so total allowable return types.

Comment: I agree with @DoanCuong.  Using an interface makes more sense for defining the contract.  A base class should be used for sharing implementations among child classes.  Since you are wanting "plugins" that would have different behaviors there is no reason to force them to use a certain base class.

Answer (score 0):

Use an IOC container such as -

1. [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. [Castle.Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=MainPage&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)
3. [Autofac](http://autofac.org/)

and others. These are all to support this kind of implementations -

I usually use MEF and Castle.Windsor for this kind of scenario. I have a blog post about MEF. Might help you

1. http://mahmudulislam.me/2012/04/20/1a-managed-extensibility-framework-introduction/
2. http://mahmudulislam.me/2012/04/30/1bcreating-the-solution/
3. http://mahmudulislam.me/2012/06/20/1c-building-blocks-for-the-core-engine/

Comment: That does not help.  I understand how to do the plugins.  Please re-read the question.